# B2 US visa for parents: husband over 80 years and wife below 80 years

Tags: usa, visa-refusals

I completed and submitted my DS 160 for B2 visa renewal and on the “Thank You“ page I added my wife’s DS 160 also and created a Family Group. While scheduling our appointment, when asked the question “Are you (the visa applicant) 80 years of age or older?” I answered yes. The US visa site generated one CGI number for the two of us and the amount of $320 ($160 for each) was deposited in the AXIS bank, and a receipt for the $320 amount was generated. The interview waiver confirmation letter is also showing me as applicant and my wife as my dependent.

I am over 80 years old, and my wife is 70 years old. I am eligible for a visa interview waiver but my spouse is not. Now how should I correct the application so that separate applicable processes for each of us can be done?

Answer (score 2):

Either you can email the USA embassy (there's a provided email) so they reset her account so you can make changes, or they will catch it themselves and invite her for interview automatically.